# Using codemirror in jquery.ui.dialog loses focus onload

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, codemirror

i try to use [codemirror](http://codemirror.net) in a jquery ui dialog.

here you can see the result in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/HtntY/

the problem is that the content in codemirror does not appear on first load. it only appears after you set focus on the editor and than type something, after that the preloaded content appears.

can this be fixed somehow. i tried to do it with the refresh() function without success.

thanks for you short time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like jQuery UI hasn't actually unhid the DIV when the opener runs. Putting a `refresh` call in a timeout (as in http://jsfiddle.net/NP9SL/ ) seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and wound up running the editor.refresh() off the focus event, FWIW. I thought I'd mention another, somewhat related problem. If you try to take advantage of the CodeMirror dialog/search functionality inside of JQueryUI modal dialog, the integrated search dialog fails to get focus and you can't type into it. Interestingly I can paste text into the search field, but I cant type. Have yet to find a way around this other than setting modal to false.

Comment: i recommend you to custom build the search function. its just few lines using the fw from cm.